# Smooth Toggle Menu on Bootstrap sub-theme

Tags: javascript, 8, theming, blocks

I'm using [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) 8.x-3.0-beta2 on Drupal 8.0.1. Originally the menu allow you to expand one at a time. I added the following smooth toggle code for animation effects.

```
$(function(){
  $('li .dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
       $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle('slow'); 
  });
});
```

The script run very well. It has the smooth animation, but it does not auto collapse when I click on the other menu. I would like to expand the menu one at a time. How can I fix this?

**** **Updated on Jan 12th 2016** ******
I have created a development site on Pantheon, which is "http://dev-cocoskin.pantheon.io".

Comment: Can you provide a snippet on a jsfiddle?

Comment: @НЛО I will create a development site on Pantheon after Holiday.

Comment: @НЛО please check the above update.